# SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char print in Android JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, swig, pjsip

I receive a structure containing the SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char in a function and I want to print this value

```
@Override
public newRs1Param sendOk(newRs1Param sas) {
    System.out.println(sas.getIdentifier());
    return sas;
}
```

with this code. But this gives to me the error:

> org.pjsip.pjsua2.SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char@4279be40

How can I solve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this *unsigned char ** should be threaten like string, you can just reuse *char ** typemap

```
%apply char * { unsigned char * };
```

Comment: where I write that? in java? :S

Comment: inside interface file (.i)